# Get AZ of a subnet through cloudformation script

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to do something like...

`"echo  --zones ",
     {
         "Ref": "az_of_subnet"
     },
" >> aws_details.txt\n"`

in the user-data of an EC2 instance which is being created through the cloudformation script. The Subnet ID of an EXISTING subnet is known. Is there a way to get the availability zone of the subnet? Currently I'm taking this as an input (az_of_subnet) from the user, which seems redundant/not right, since I already know the subnet-id.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a custom Lambda function to get the AZ for the VPC subnet ID.

There are a number of oddities about availability zones. My us-west-2a may or my not be the same as your us-west-2a. Amazon randomizes the actual data centers to load balance, etc.

Here is a link on how to create a custom function that CloudFormation can call.

[AWS Lambda-backed Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html)

An interesting article about CloudFormation and Availability Zones

[Using Lambda to get a users Availability Zone list in Cloud Formation](https://www.kencochrane.net/2017/03/29/using-lambda-to-get-azs-in-cloudformation/)

Comment: us-west-2 is a region, us-west-2a vs us-west2b fits your example more appropriately.

Comment: Thank Chris, I update my answer to correct the typo on AZ names.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the reply. I was wondering whether there's  any easier and more compact way to do this, like in one line or so?
I'm currently using boto client to get the information which works fine but it seems messy and lengthy. Similar to your solution. Is there no functionality that AWS CF provides to query the already existing resource properties?
Seems like a must have feature but couldn't find anything online :(

Comment: There is no function built into CloudFormation that either maps a subnet ID to AZ or gets a list of subnets with AZ information.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been kicking this around a bit and wonder why you just can't use an SSM Stored Parameter? Yes, it's a few minutes of work to get it set up, but once it's set, it's not like it will change much.

Go into SSM, create a Stored Parameter... SubnetId for the name, AZ for the parameter. Since the Subnets are already created, then the info is there. You can even output this info from CFN into SSM if you work at it to auto-populate SSM when CFN creations are done.

You can then pull that into your CloudFormation template pretty easy.

Best place to go look is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

I feel that SSM Stored Parameters is often overlooked when you want to make your CFN templates a lot more dynamic. I have templates that, literally, can run in any environment without modification by using SSM.

Like I said though, it takes a little work to set it up, but a little bit here and there goes a long way.

You can see an example here on [my repo](https://github.com/Talderon/AWS_CloudFormation/tree/master/ElasticSearch/VPC/SSM_Params). I have both YAML and JSON examples.

Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Looks like AP wanted to use existing subnet which is not created in that cloud formation. So this is not currently supported in CloudFormation , so there might be 2 options(may be more)
1. Call APIs in user data script to get the AZ
2. Use terrform which supports this functionality

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong...Here, "mySubnet" needs to be the name of a  resource which is being created in the same CloudFormation script. I need to get the AZ of an already existing subnet ( ID of which is known in the CF-script )

Comment: Yes, its the subnet you want to refer. It will work if you created that subnet in same template but looks like you are passing existing subnet. hence I don't think its possible with cloudformation you need to use API call using python boto or any suitable language inside your userdata script or use terrfaform.

Answer (score -2):

Lambda seems overkill; you can issue a curl command against the instance metadata:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
```

Throw this into your user-data to get the AZ

Comment: You cannot get meta-data for an instance from CloudFormation (exception: you are running CloudFormation in an EC2 instance). The question is how to map a subnet ID to an AZ in a CloudFormation template.

Comment: If you're needing this in user data, you're already on the box and thus have access to the metadata. The user data can get this value itself, no need to make CF do it.

Comment: The userdata is valid at the time the instance was launched. The subnets may be quite different at a later date. Metadata does not have a mapping for subnet IDs to AZs. The question is how to create a CloudFormation template that matches subnets to AZ. You may be launching CloudFormation on one EC2 instance to create other instances or services.

Comment: @ChrisPollard, thanks for the reply but that API will get me the AZ in which the launched EC2 instance is.
I, instead, need to get the AZ of a subnet with given ID.
The instance which is accessing that information will not be in the same subnet.